# C# How to check whether the first number in a (int,int) is bigger/smaller than the first number in another (int,int)

Tags: c#, integer

So, I have two (int, int) variables and I need to check, whether ONE number in the first variable is bigger than one number in the other. Is there a way to do that?

```
(int, int) _dblint = (5, 10);
(int, int) _dblint2 = (3, 10);
```

Can I somehow tell that the first number in _dblint is bigger the in _dblint2, but the second numbers are equal?

Comment: Pretty sure you can access each item via the `.Item1` property etc

Comment: Where is your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that by comparing the [`ValueTuple.Item1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2.item1) and [`ValueTuple.Item2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2.item2) fields.

Try something like this:

```
if (_dblint.Item1 > _dblint2.Item1 &&
    _dblint.Item2 == _dblint2.Item2)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Moreover, when declaring the tuples, you may give custom names to the fields. For example:

```
// X and Y are just examples. You may use any other names that work for you.
(int X, int Y) _dblint = (5, 10);
(int X, int Y) _dblint2 = (3, 10);
```

In that case, you can compare them like this:

```
if (_dblint.X > _dblint2.X && _dblint.Y == _dblint2.Y)
{
    // Do something
}
```